# How to remove html tag in android

Tags: android, html, xml

my question is how to remove all tag like `<br></br><p></>` etc in `TextView`.
how to remove all tags please reply me
reply me immediately as soon as possible
many try to solve this problem but not proper answer 
my apps is news app and all data are fetch in php server side and if description share then all html tags are share

thanks

Comment: Do you not want to display the content in a web view then as this will display the html content as is?

Comment: yes i am use in webview in html content

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView tv;
tv.setText(tv.getText().toString().replaceAll("<.*?>",""));
```

It uses non-greedy regular expression <.*?> to match everything having pattern <...>. I hope your text
doesn't use < > for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) like below,

```
public static String convertHtmlToText(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.......its working and i save my days

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it helps.It will let other users know that this question got a working solution.